# How to add a new action to the existing controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new in Rails. Sorry for the noob question.

I've create a new controller: `rails new controller Say hello goodbye`

How can i add a new action like "hello" and "goodbye" to this existing controller?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Add a new action is simple. All you have to do is add a method on your controller, like, for example:

```
# app/controllers/dummy_controller.rb
def get_back
  logger.warn "It works!"
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Now, to be able to access this action throgh a URL, you need to have a route for that. This is done in your `config/routes.rb` file. You can add it as a hard route, like

```
get '/go_back', to: "dummy#get_back"
```

This is the simplest possible route. But you might want it to behave like a restful route. This is useful if you are doing an action over one or more models. So in your route file, you will have something like this:

```
resources :dummy do
  collection do
    get 'get_back'
  end
end
```

This allows you to accept a `get` method over a collection. You will have the helper `dummy_go_back_url`, and to get to this page the url is `/dummies/go_back`.

This is for acting over a collection of resources. If you are acting on one specific object, you should specify a `member` action:

```
resources :dummy do
  member do
    get 'get_back'
  end
end
```

Since a member action is for only one object, you will have a url like `/dummies/123/go_back`. This automatically will set the variable `params[:id]` in your controller to `123`, allowing you to easily fetch your object. Also, the helper method `dummy_go_back_path` is defined, and received one object or id as parameter to generate the correct url.

These are the most simple routes you can have, but you can look in [routing outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) from rails guides as a reliable source of information.

Comment: Best answer I could find in the web. You rock!

Comment: Hero righ here! :D

Answer (score 9):

```
def hello
  @hello = "hello"
end

def goodbye
  @goodbye = "goodbye"
end
```

then in `/config/routes.rb`

```
get 'foo/hello'       ## foo is the name of your controller
get 'foo/goodbye'
```

Remember to create the views too:
`views/foo/hello.html.erb` that may look like this:

```
Say <%= @hello %>
```

`views/foo/goodbye.html.erb` that may look like this:

```
 Say <%= @goodbye %>
```

Answer (score 5):

When you repeat the `generate` command with another method's name, you can skip overwriting the existing controller and it's test implementation. That will automatically add the route and create a view. After that you have to add the method manually to the controller because that action didn't touch the controller file.

Rails 6.1 additional info is in the comments below.

---

Example:

one method called `new` was already created in the controller when it was initially created:

```
$ rails generate controller Person new
... successfully created the controller, it's route and view ...
```

when trying to add a new method:

```
$ rails generate controller Person all
Running via Spring preloader in process 28648
    conflict  app/controllers/person_controller.rb
Overwrite ../app/controllers/person_controller.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] h
    Y - yes, overwrite
    n - no, do not overwrite
    a - all, overwrite this and all others
    q - quit, abort
    d - diff, show the differences between the old and the new
    h - help, show this help
Overwrite ../app/controllers/person_controller.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip  app/controllers/person_controller.rb
       route  get 'person/all'
      invoke  erb
       exist    app/views/person
      create    app/views/person/all.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
    conflict    test/controllers/person_controller_test.rb
Overwrite ../test/controllers/person_controller_test.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip    test/controllers/person_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
   identical    app/helpers/person_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
   identical      app/assets/javascripts/person.coffee
      invoke    scss
   identical      app/assets/stylesheets/person.scss
```

Comment: Suggested edit queue is full so I'll add this as a comment: In rails 6.1 I needed to add `--skip-collision-check` to the second generate command. After that the process was the same... say 'No' to overwriting the controller and add the new method to the controller file manually, everything else gets generated

Answer (score 0):

You simply open controller file (in app/controllers/) and define new methods there. However, if you generated this controller (say_controller) the way you wrote, those two actions should already be there.