# How to call a method from controller using link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I want my app to add a book to current_user when he clicks the link. My code seems to be ok, there are no errors but after user clicks the link nothing happens.

book.rb:

```
has_many :book_users
has_many :users, through: :book_users
```

user.rb:

```
has_many :book_users
has_many :books, through: :book_users
```

book_user.rb:

```
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :user
```

books_controller.rb:

```
before_action :is_admin?, except: [:book_params, :add_to_books_i_read, :index]
before_filter :authenticate_user!
expose(:book, attributes: :book_params)
expose(:books)


  def create
    if book.save
      redirect_to(book)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if book.save
      redirect_to(book)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def add_to_books_i_read(book_id)
    current_user.books << Book.find(book_id)
  end
```

In my index view I have

```
ul
  -books.each do |book|
    li
      = link_to "#{book.name}", book_path(book)
      = link_to "  Add to my books", {:controller => "books", method: :add_to_books_i_read, book_id: :book.id}
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Why my method add_to_books_i_read does nothing? The table in database book_users doesn't record anything after clicking this link_to, but it works well itself (I checked via console). What can I do? How to make users add books through the method and how to call this method correctly? Every help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh God. With your advise help I've finally got it! So,

Controller:

```
def add_to_books_i_read
    current_user.books << Book.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(:back) #this line
end
```

In routes

```
resources :books do
    member do
      get :add_to_books_i_read
    end
end
```

index view

```
-books.each do |book|
    li
      = link_to "#{book.name}", book_path(book)
      = link_to  "       Add to my books", add_to_books_i_read_book_path(book)
```

Thank you all for your help! I'm really really grateful! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  = link_to "  Add to my books", {:controller => "books", action: :add_to_books_i_read, book_id: :book.id}
```

Comment: Yes, it's ok with admin. And yes, it is called

Comment: there is typo on the end of parameters: `book_id: :book.id`
should be `book: book.id`

Comment: can you give us logs such as:
`Processing by BooksController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"book_id"=>"1"}`

Answer (score 1):

The first, [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) in the `link_to` is the `symbol of HTTP verb` so you can not pass your function in the controller
To define and use new action on you controller you need to define route for that [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703349/how-to-add-a-new-action-to-the-existing-controller)

Answer (score 1):

Since `add_to_books_i_read` is a controller action method you should update your routes to include this action for `books` resources in order to play nicely with Rails way of doing thing in a resourceful way. You also get to use a URL helper for this path that will look like this:

`/books/:id/add_to_books_i_read`

Your code could look like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :books do
  get :add_to_books_i_read, on: :member
end

# app/controller/books_controller.rb
def add_to_books_i_read
  current_user.books << Book.find(params[:id])
  # redirect or other logic
end

# app/views/books/index.html.haml
ul
  - books.each do |book|
    li
      = link_to "#{book.name}", book_path(book)
      = link_to "Add to my books", add_to_books_i_read_book_path(book)
```

Comment: Well, I did all this, but now there is an error when i'm on /books page: undefined method `add_to_books_i_read_book_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000006fe2cb0>:0x00000006f85678> but it exists in routes file as you advised. 
When I do rake routes it says /books/:book_id/add_to_books_i_read(.:format) It looks suspicious because in all other actions it's just books/:id not books/:book_id
What do you think?

Comment: Hmm.. I updated the code with `get :add_to_books_i_read, on: :member`. Could u give it another shot?

Answer (score 1):

Also try to organize your routes as (note member section)

```
resources :books do 
  member do
    get :add_to_books_i_read
  end
end
```

and see Prefix Verb column in rake routes output.

Answer (score 1):

From @Ioannis Tziligkakis, I edited a bit.

Try:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :books do
  member do
    get :add_to_books_i_read
  end
end

# app/controller/books_controller.rb
def add_to_books_i_read
  current_user.books << Book.find(params[:id])
  # redirect or other logic
end

# app/views/books/index.html.haml
ul
  - books.each do |book|
    li
      = link_to "#{book.name}", book_path(book)
      = link_to "Add to my books", add_to_books_i_read_book_path(book.id)
```

Comment: An error occurs - Template is missing. I read that it could happen because of create action, but I don't get where do I call it (

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :books do
  # just not about method:
  # use get for request, search
  # use put for update
  # use post for create
  # use delete for destroy
  put :add_to_books_i_read, on: :member
end

# app/controller/books_controller.rb
def add_to_books_i_read
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  current_user.books << @book
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

# app/views/books/index.html.haml
ul
  - books.each do |book|
    li{:id => "book_#{book.id}"}
      = render "links", book: book

# add field: app/views/books/_links.html.haml
= link_to "#{book.name}", book_path(book)
= link_to "Add to my books", add_to_books_i_read_book_path(book), method: :put, remote: true

# add field: app/views/books/add_to_books_i_read.js.erb
$("#book_<%= @book.id %>").html("<%= j render 'books/links', book: @book %>")
```

Comment: An error occurs - Template is missing. I read that it could happen because of create action, but I don't get where do I call it (

Comment: I know what happened. Do you want to do it with ajax or not. I can help you @Jakov.

Comment: I just updated the answer. Hope this work for you @Jakov :D